# When Arjuna defeated all the Kuru warriors in the Virat war, then why did he kill them through deceit in the Kurukshetra war?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, karna, bhishma, dronacharya

In Virat war all Kuru warriors including Bhisma Drona and Karna were vanquished by Arjuna.

**Go Haran Parva 62**
[image]

Now, the same Arjuna in Kurukshetra war even with Lord Krishna with him, could not face these warriors. Arjuna killed each and every Kuru warrior through deceit.

**Shalya Badha Parva 60**

[image]

Lord Krishna also accepted that Karna, Bhishma and Drona could not be vanquished by Pandavas in a fair combat. Then how Arjuna defeated all of them in Virata war?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did moha (disillusion) arise in Arjuna only before the Kurukshetra war in Mahabharata but not the previous battles?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14245/why-did-moha-disillusion-arise-in-arjuna-only-before-the-kurukshetra-war-in-ma)

Comment: I think it’s because he used the Sammohana Astra so they all fell asleep in the Virat war, without countering Arjunas attack. Whereas in the main war they were actually fighting.

Comment: @ArchM before using sammohana Astra he already defeated all Kuru warriors.

Comment: Interesting, didn’t know this

Comment: @PrasannaR, Actually No, if you read through Mahabharat, Arjun changed his female appearance before fighting in the Virat battle, and everyone knew they were fighting Arjun. and the Samohana Astra was used quite late into battle after Arjun individually defeated all of them and then again defeated them collectively. He also managed to kill one of Karna's brother (from his step parent's side, not kunti) during the battle.

Comment: Virata war was defense (live). Kurukshetra war was offense (kill).

Comment: @ V. Aggarwal Yes. As per Wiki Arjuna promised to bring pieces of clothing of Kauravas as war souvenir to Uttara ( Virat's daughter). Clothes should not be picked up from the bodies of the dead, so they had to be put to sleep after defeating them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He didn't kill them in Virata war. They were still alive until Kurkushetra. Karna had the best weapon, Bishma had a boon to chose how to die, and Drona had to lay down his weapons. So it's not like they could ever have been killed straight on. Arjuna wasn't the strongest warrior and neither was Krishna, only Krishna was fully aware of that unlike Arjuna. So they had to improvise. And no matter how good of a warrior, you can't exactly kill someone fairly who can't be killed fairly due to a boon.

Comment: I think you are trying to distinguish between killing and defeating in wars and adding justification for deceit. You can make it bit clear by elaborating answer. Also it would be better if you can cite some sources.

Comment: What is unclear? They have been killed how they have been killed because there was no other way to kill them. For example karna was cursed to have his skills fail him when he needed theem most, so there you go, that was his only weakness, and this wasn't a tournament this was war, it wasn't arjunas fault karnas chariot got stuck or whatever so that he couldn't fight, that was his (karnas)karma, arjuna had to swallow his pride and take him out, otherwise he and his army would have been taken out.

Comment: actual according to rule of battle that Pandavas and Kauravas agreed on, one can not attack foot soldier while being on a chariot

Comment: You mean Karna was a foot soldier for a moment  when he got down to lift his chariot  out of cracked ground ?

Answer (score 1):

Want to improve this post? Add citations from reputable sources by editing the post. Posts with unsourced content may be edited or deleted.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m04/m04061.htm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhishma_Parva https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m04/m04067.htm https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m04/m04066.htm https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m04/m04067.htm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astra_(weapon)#Astras_in_Hindu_Epics https://www.isrgrajan.com/bhishma-pitamah-karan-and-arjun-what-were-the-greatest-difference.html

Arjuna has defeated all the kauravas and karna. He fought Drona and Kripa but defeated them. Kripa said all 6 warriors including bhishma, kripa himself, drona, karna and others should attack him simultaneously as he thought arjuna was able to defeat Nivatakavacha whom indrajit and ravana could not defat together and defeated gods included indra but Bhishma alone went to fight Arjuna and shovered a lot of arrows at each other and both of them not being injured. Bhishma pierced Uttara and Arjuna aimed and released arrow at Bhishmaś charioteer but Bhishma caught hold of the arrow in mid-air itself and threw the arrow that pierced him. Uttar then drove the chariot speedily at Karna, Kripa, and Drona as ordered by Arjuna where Arjuna defeated those and ONLY those three, not Bhishma. Arjuna invokes indrastra, which has a lot of arrows but bhishma nullified it with vayu astra releasing wind.  Arjuna then used sailastra to nullify vayuvyastra. He then rushed to drona, kripa and others because they were the ones who stole the castle. Arjuna then invokes Sammohana astra that collapses the maharathis Karna, Drona, Kripa, Duryodhana and other 99 kauravas. Also, the main purpose of the Virata war was fought to steal the wealth of Matsya king Virata and main purpose was to find and catch the pandavas before the 13th year of disguise

Methinks, Bhishma is not stupefied, for he knoweth how to counteract this weapon of mine. So, pass thou on, keeping his steeds to thy left; for those that are sensible should thus be avoided.

See, Arjuna clearly states that Bhishma knows how to counter attack the Sammohana astra